# Eigenvalues of $2 \times 2$ block matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

What are the eigenvalues of the following block matrix?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & J \\ 
J^T & B
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are any square matrices of order $n$, $J$ is one matrix of order $n$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Please explain "one matrix of order $n$".